# Emacs. Search w\o mouse

Tags: search, emacs

Very basic question I can't find an answer to in google.

How can I input search a string in emacs with out using mouse to put cursor in "command line"? Is there a key combination for this?

I mean to do just:

C-s, [press some keys], [insert search string], Enter. and the string is found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just press <kbd>C-s</kbd> and start typing your search term. Press <kbd>C-s</kbd> to jump to the next result.

You can also paste text behind the `I-Search`: in the Minibuffer using

<kbd>C-y</kbd>

So you can mark stuff with <kbd>C-Space</kbd>, copy it with <kbd>M-w</kbd>, search with <kbd>C-s</kbd>, and paste your selection with <kbd>C-y</kbd>.

An even better way may be this: directly search for what your cursor is currently at: <kbd>C-s C-w</kbd>. Subsequent presses of <kbd>C-w</kbd> add more words to your current search.

Answer (score 3):

What version of emacs are you using ? In my version, if I press C-s, my cursor (the real one, not the one blinking on textarea) is set on the « command line ».

Answer (score 0):

You can press Enter after C-s and then you can type anything there.